# Is there a good way to print out a flattened namespace for a JSON-like trie structure (iterative solution only) in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, traversal, trie

I'm attempting to create a trie structure in C++, where each node holds a name, and some data, and can hold references to children nodes of any number.

I'd like to traverse my trie such that I print out the "flattened" path to a given node in an iterative fashion.

Given some Tree where a node is defined by:

```
    class Node
    {
            public:
            virtual std::string node_name() = 0;
    };


    class TreeNode : Node
    {
    public:
        std::string name;
        std::map<std::string, TreeNode&> children {};


        TreeNode(const std::string&name) : name(name) {}


        std::string node_name()
        {
            return name;
        }

        void add_child(TreeNode& node)
        {
                children.insert(std::pair<std::string, TreeNode&> 
                (node.node_name(), node));
        }

    };
```

If I add children via:

```
    TreeNode root { "root" };

    TreeNode a { "a" };
    TreeNode b { "b" };

    TreeNode c { "c" };
    TreeNode d { "d" };
    TreeNode e { "e" };


    a.add_child(c);
    a.add_child(d);

    b.add_child(e);

    root.add_child(a);
    root.add_child(b);

    // flatten the tree and print out the namespace here
    flatten(root);
```

The output should be (don't care about order):

```
    root
    root.a
    root.a.c
    root.a.d
    root.b
    root.b.e
```

I've already implemented the recursive solution (see below), but I'd like to know if there's a way to do this iteratively (since I'd like to avoid recursion if possible in my application).

Here is the recursive version:

```
    void flatten_helper(TreeNode& root, 
                        const std::string& prefix)
    {
        static const std::string delimeter { "." };

        std::string namespace_path(prefix);
        if (!prefix.empty())
        {
            namespace_path.append(delimeter);
        }

        namespace_path.append(root.node_name());

        for (auto& node : root.children)
        {
            flatten_helper(node.second, namespace_path);
        }
        // do something with node/complete namespace name
        std::cout << namespace_path << std::endl;


    }

    void flatten(TreeNode& node)
    {
        std::string empty {""};

        return flatten_helper(node, empty);
    }



    int main(int argc, char** argv)
    {
        TreeNode root { "root" };

        TreeNode a { "a" };
        TreeNode b { "b" };

        TreeNode c { "c" };
        TreeNode d { "d" };
        TreeNode e { "e" };


        a.add_child(c);
        a.add_child(d);

        b.add_child(e);

        root.add_child(a);
        root.add_child(b);

        flatten(root);

        return 0;
    }
```

I'm a bit stumped on how to approach the iterative version in c++11 (have tried a few iterations of various tree traversals) - any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to converting recursive processes into interative processes is to make the 'pending work' explicit. In your case, a unit of work is a `TreeNode` and a prefix, and the work units are kept in a `std::stack` (as your recursive solution is depth-first). Any (previously) recursive calls must add work to the stack, and work stops when no more work is available.

```
void flatten_iter(TreeNode& root_node)
{
    using WorkItem = std::pair<TreeNode&, std::string>;
    static const std::string delimeter{ "." };

    std::stack<WorkItem> workitems;
    workitems.emplace(root_node, "");

    while (!workitems.empty()) {
        auto [ node, prefix ] = workitems.top();
        workitems.pop();

        std::string namespace_path(prefix);
        if (!prefix.empty())
        {
            namespace_path.append(delimeter);
        }

        namespace_path.append(node.node_name());

        for (auto& child : node.children)
        {
            workitems.emplace(child.second, namespace_path);
        }

        // do something with node/complete namespace name
        std::cout << namespace_path << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This `stack<WorkItem>` representation also lends itself to an easy pre-order iterator: `begin` is just the root node, `operator++` pops the top node and adds the child nodes, `end` is the empty stack. Suggest you try it as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation and exercise (I’ll try that next). I had half the solution (using a stack w/ depth first iteration), but negated to apply the prefix as a “work item.”

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid using a stack at all is to have parent pointers in your tree.

Your iterator can chase down the tree, process all the peer nodes in the bottom branch, and then use the parent pointer in the last node to get back up 1 level, move on to the next peer node at that level, and go down again. In the end, it is a relatively minimal algorithm.

Of course, with a large tree, the cost of parent pointers on every node is /much/ more than the cost of an explicit stack, but if you have another use for parent pointers, it is worth considering.